# Does the Canon WFT-E4 support recording video directly into a usb hard drive?

Tags: canon, video, canon-5d-mark-ii, usb

Does anyone know if you can use a Canon 5Dmk2 + WFT-E4 to record 1080p HD footage directly into a USB hard drive?

Even without having a CF card inside the camera?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Seems it is not possible

http://twitter.com/#!/davidobm/status/92622013805494272

> "Pity that Canon's 5D MkII wireless adapter (WFT E4 II) WFT server mode doesn't support the ability to record video"